# MSSQL get a table with (months + year) between two dates

Tags: sql-server

I have to get a table with month + year between two dates using MSSQL server. 
Lets say the given dates are 01/02/2012 to 05/04/2012. Then the table should look like this

```
 Feb 2012
 Mar 2012
 April 2012
```

Any suggestions for achieving this is highly appreciated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE 
      @start DATE = '20120201'
    , @end DATE = '20120405'

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT dt = DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@start) - 1), @start)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, dt)
    FROM cte
    WHERE dt < DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(@end) - 1), @end)
)
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(4), dt, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), dt, 120) 
FROM cte
```

**Output:**

```
--------
Feb 2012
Mar 2012
Apr 2012
```